# Posting to a Facebook page programmatically and not manually

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cron

I need to know how to post statuses programatically on a facebook page. My aim is to use this in combination with cron. I'm not sure of how to do things because there is no information about the logged user and the facebook API won't let me post without permissions.

Is there any way to achieve this?

P.S: I tried to google but all the results were about posting to page when the admin manually triggers it.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/

Comment: I rewrote the question and voted to reopen it as the question by itself is a worthy one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, by requesting an extended token and saving it on the database when you login with the admin account.

Everytime you access an app wich you already granted permissions a token is generated, if you store that token on your database along with the id of the user, you can use it for the next 60 days(I'm not sure if it's really 60 or 30 days ), after that the token expires, to make sure that doesn't happen you just have to visit the app once a month to renew the token.

If you use php sdk you can get that extended token by doing this:

```
$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

You can read more about it here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/